# WoW: Post-Cataclysm zone levels?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Horde progression through the new Azeroth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11628/horde-progression-through-the-new-azeroth)

I have WoW alts of all levels, and I have no idea where each of them should be leveling now.

I've found two resources that help, but are far from complete:

http://media.mmo-champion.com/images/news/2010/november/levelflow.jpg
http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/1126992742

Does anyone know of a better guide, post-Cataclysm, for what areas are best for what level ranges?

Comment: Check the answers in this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11628/horde-progression-through-the-new-azeroth

Comment: What's wrong with the MMO-Champion link?  Looks solid to me...

Comment: One major change is that zones now appear to only intended for a 5 level range, instead of 10 like the original game.  This is due to how zones have been split and traffic has been rerouted to streamline things.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.wowpedia.org/Zones

I think this was updated post-Cataclysm...

Answer (score -1):

The [Hero's call boards](http://www.wowpedia.org/Hero's_Call_Board) (alliance) and the [Warchief's Command Boards](http://www.wowpedia.org/Warchief's_Command_Board) (horde) where put in to answer the "where should I go to quest?" question. Check them out at major Azeroth quest hubs.

EDIT: Thanks for the heads up all, edited post.

Comment: This is flat out wrong -- I can personally attest that I've received two quests from the Hero's Call Board not on that list -- Bloodmyst Isle and Ashenvale. The wowhead entry itself lists 21 quests, and there very well might be more: http://www.wowhead.com/object=206111

Comment: As @raven notes, this is just one more bullet in the WoWWiki is out of date and not to be trusted list. See WoWPedia for a far more complete list: http://www.wowpedia.org/Hero%27s_Call_Board