# Progression in Wow that avoids spiders

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I love WoW but I have arachnophobia, so I was looking for a progression that avoids them as much as possible (or totally, if possible). Don't mind race or class.
Greetings

Comment: What kind of progression are you looking for? Do you want to start a completely new account or do you have a max level character already and want to progress through the game to level another one? Or are you looking for a certain part of the game (eg lvl 40 - 60)? Because leveling alone is easiest by talking to Chromie and picking an expansion with a low to no spider pop or simply through dungeon finder (excluding dungeons known to have spiders) or PVP (where only mounts and hunter pets can be spiders).

Comment: New account, if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Progression through WoW that avoids spiders](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75918/progression-through-wow-that-avoids-spiders) - Nowadays a large portion of it is even easier due to Chromie time, so the bad bits mentioned in the linked post can largely be skipped

Answer (score 2):

Nearly impossible seeing Hunters can tame Spiders and use them as pets.
So chances are high you will run in to them in major cities.

Also nearly all forest have spiders, then you got ice spiders in Northrend, lava spiders in the areas around Blackrock mountain...

- Undead areas got graphic imagery concerning spiders (stay out of
  Hillsbrad foothills even without Arachnophobia that place is a
  nightmare fuel involving spiders).
- Avoid any area with Forrest/Woods in it (So Night Elf and Human areas
  are no go's)
- Avoid Northrend and the Plaugelands (unless you are ok with zombie
  spiders).
- Also avoid Silithus and anything that sounds Egyptian (the Egyptian
  cultures in wow are mostly Spider based (Qiraj/Nerubians)

Below i added a map, all the red area's have spiders...this is not including other worlds you will need to travel to and most dungeons that might have em. So i guess going Tauren would be the safest option (perhaps trolls/orcs)
[image]